# Android .apk doubles size depending on dev box used to deploy since v17 tools

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, apk

After updating to ADT r17 tools, we're having the issue of some dev boxes with classes.dex file within the .apk being 3.2MB vs 700KB. In addition to the inflated dex file, the application can't be launched from a device. It spits out a ClassNotFoundException.

We're at a loss, since all project/eclipse settings appear to be the same across dev boxes.

The project itself consists of two library projects and main project with the supportv4.jar and an in house jar.

*Update*

I chose the export the library projects and the jars (in the main project) and it works when it deploys onto the device, the .apk is still double the size. Another fun part is (on the boxes it doesn't work) we have a 50% fail rate on launching (that is eclipse freezes). So it is still essentially unusable still.  At r16 tools there was no problem on any box getting it to build and launch.

*Update v0.2*

I had library project 1 depend on library project 2 and added the neccesary jars only to lib1. It launches and runs, but still takes 3-4 minutes per change to the source to recomplie/build/deploy and the apk is still x2 the normal size.

*Update v0.3*

Even more fun, it will compile quickly via the command line, but not via eclipse. I'm still getting a very large .apk (7.16MB vs 3.xxMB for a previously "normal" apk).

*Update v0.4*

Turns out, even with an updated sdk/adt some box's eclipse are using adt 15/16 (help-> about eclipse -> instillation details) with no complaints. Those were the functional boxes....

**UPDATE V0.5**

They released tool r18 today which "remedy" the issues, but the apk is still twice the "original" size and the build takes quite a while to complete. We ended up consolidating the project to one project, not a satisfactory answer by a long shot, but we couldn't waste any more cycles debugging our tools.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this if you are adding the jars to each project (the way it worked in ADT16, etc). Additionally, ADT17 automatically ads jars under libs/, so if you have older versions of jars, you might get problems. Put the jars under the library project's lib/, remove any jars 
you've added to the main projects build classpath.

Comment: Unless the jars are the exact same, then the compiler will phase out the duplicate.

Comment: ADT17 does check and issue some warnings for 'version' based on the (IIRC) SHA1 sum, but old stuff can still be included: if you have lib-1.0.jar and lib-2.0.jar under libs/, both will be added. Details: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: Which would mean that unless they are the exact same file they will be included multiple times, which is what I said.

Comment: @HandlerExploit Hm, 'phase out' == 'include multiple times'?

Comment: My bad I wrote that incorrectly, when the jars are the exact same the compile will phase out the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikolays answer you might want to look into the proguard setup. That is now different and might remove a whole bunch of stuff when you are using r17 vs an older release.